# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$5: (string) => double)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, sparkr

It's R code below:

```
train_feature   <- loadDF("./resultFile/train_feature",
                          "csv",
                          header = TRUE)

predict_feature <- loadDF("./resultFile/predict_feature", 
                          "csv",
                          header = TRUE)

model <- spark.randomForest( 
    train_feature,
    forward_count ~ max_forward + sum_forward,
    type          = "regression", 
    maxDepth      = 16,
    maxBins       = 32,
    maxMemoryInMB = 512
)

predict_result <- predict(model, predict_feature)

prediction     <- select(predict_result, "prediction")

prediction$prediction <- cast(prediction$prediction, "integer")

head(prediction, 200)
```

The error is:

> Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 45.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 45.0 (TID 872, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined
>   function($anonfun$5: **(string) => double**)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)

Then I cast the data type:

```
train_feature$sum_forward   <- cast(train_feature$sum_forward,   'double')
train_feature$max_forward   <- cast(train_feature$max_forward,   'double')
train_feature$forward_count <- cast(train_feature$forward_count, 'double')
```

It still doesn't work with the another error below:

> Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) :
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Data type StringType is not
>   supported**.  at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$transformSchema$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$transformSchema$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:117)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.transformSchema(VectorAssembler.scala:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$$anonfun$transformSchema$5.apply(Pipeline.scala:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$$anonfun$transformSchema$5.apply(Pipeline.scala:310)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>     at org.apache.s

But when I changed the formula to **forward_count ~ X1 + X2** without casting datatype evenly,it works normally.ALL features were computed by function of SparkMLlib.

This is a part of train data:
[train_feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaXDx.png)

Comment: did you find a solution by any chance ?